Changing bounds in marginal density
I have the function p(x,y) = 24x for 0<x, x+y<1, x<y.
I want to find the marginal density of Y, which means I have to integrate over x. My TA told me I have to split the area I want to integrate in two parts, y∈(0,$\frac{1}{2}$) where the upper bound is equal y, and from y ∈ ($\frac{1}{2}$,1) where the upper bound is equal 1-y. But why do I need to do this? Why not just the upper bound y over the entire area?

I wonder if you misunderstood because the joint density is zero for $x > 1/2$. In any event if you construct a contour plot of the joint density, things will be clearer.

I have done so, and I get that y ranges from (0,1) and x from (0,1/2). I still don't understand why I have to change boundaries.

You want to evaluate $f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$, so you need to figure out the correct limits for $x$ for every possible value of $y$.
Here is the support of the joint density:

Imagine drawing a horizontal line through this plot. Where does it fall inside the support? The lower bound is always $x=0$, but what is the upper bound?
